# chrome.debugger cannot listen to an inner frame after chrome update

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension with `chrome.debugger` listening to all requests and responses on a site.
It worked correctly on old chrome 62 but is broken after 73.

`backgroud.js:`

```
chrome.debugger.onEvent.addListener(function (source, method, params) {
  ... // Receiving data
}
```

`manifest.json:`

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "name": "Lost Soul of Kamihime",
  "short_name": "LSK",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "all_frames": true,
      "js": [
        "lib/jquery-2.1.1.min.js",
        "lib/jquery.sprintf.js",
        "src/data.js",
        "src/common.js",
        "src/verify.js",
        "src/battle.js",
        "src/my-page.js",
        "src/weapon.js",
        "src/persist.js",
        "src/deck.js",
        "src/bot.js",
        "app.js"
      ],
      "css": [
        "css/pure.css",
        "css/panel.css",
        "css/battle.css"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "*://www.dmm.co.jp/netgame/social/-/gadgets/=/app_id=242584*",
        "*://pc-play.games.dmm.co.jp/play/kamipror*",
        "*://pc-play.games.dmm.com/play/kamipro*",
        "*://*.kamihimeproject.net/*",
        "*://osapi.dmm.com/gadgets/ifr*.kamihimeproject.net*"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "description": "Lost Soul of Kamihime",
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "tabs",
    "debugger",
    "cookies",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "options_page": "settings/index.html",
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "src/preventResize.js",
    "src/kh-*.js",
    "test-*.json",
    "src/*.html"
  ]
}
```

The site is a web game and has an inner frame, debugger caught all data including the frame, but now only the outer page.

Is there any security change for chrome, and what can I do now? The `What's New` page for offical development site stops at version 40 :(

Thank you!

Comment: paste manifest.json

Comment: New Chrome has "site isolation" enabled by default so you'll have to attach to the iframe target manually (for example by using [Target](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Target) domain).

Comment: manifest.json pasted, thank you.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you for the hint, do you have a more complete example?

Comment: No I don't have any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is `Site Isolation` policy in new Chrome, and it does not support `dev` yet.

So the fastest solution is to disable it, in `chrome://flags` turn on `Disable site isolation`.